# Get auto_increment id from table

Tags: c#, sql, .net, auto-increment

I have this code:

```
string conStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["BackgammonGame"].ConnectionString;
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conStr);
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            cmd.Connection = con;

            con.Open();
            cmd.CommandText = ("INSERT INTO Game (playerA, playerB) OUTPUT INSERTED.gameID VALUES (@playerA, @playerB)");

            cmd.Parameters.Add("@playerA", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = firstPlayer;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@playerB", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = secondPlayer;

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            int id = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
            con.Close();
```

When I insert into this table, I have an auto_increment int primary key column called `gameID`, and I declared in the sql statement that I want the `gameID` in output.
my problem is that when I write this line in the code:   `int id = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();`  the inserted parameters apear twice in the table (2 rows with the same info.), but when I delete it it's ok.

I need this row so I can use this id in other table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your command text with this and try

```
cmd.CommandText = ("INSERT INTO Game (playerA, playerB) VALUES (@playerA,@playerB); 
                     SELECT  SCOPE_IDENTITY()");
```

`SCOPE IDENTITY` returns the identity value of last inserted row. Hence that will returns the identity filed of the inserted row using the insert query

**EDIT**

You are executing the query two times

```
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); // Avoid this
int id = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();// This is enough
```

In both case your query gets executed and it cause insertion twice.
`ExecuteNonQuery()` will execute the insert query and will returns the number of rows affected.

Where as `ExecuteScalar()` will return the result of the `select scope_identity()` staement which is the identity column of the inserted row.

Here is your code

```
 con.Open();
 cmd.CommandText = ("INSERT INTO Game (playerA, playerB) VALUES (@playerA,@playerB); 
                     SELECT  SCOPE_IDENTITY()"); 

 cmd.Parameters.Add("@playerA", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = firstPlayer;
 cmd.Parameters.Add("@playerB", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = secondPlayer;

 int id = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
 con.Close();
```

Comment: SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() give me the inserted id ?  now i get an exception on the line: int id = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar(); the exception is that the cast is not ok.

Comment: SCOPE IDENTITY returns the identity value of inserted row

Comment: also try casting `Convert.Toint32(cmd.ExecuteScalar())` like this

Comment: it is still insert two rows instead of one.. what could be the problem of it ?

Comment: avoid `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()`  `cmd.ExecuteScalar()` is enough. you are calling both thats why it is inserted twice

Comment: that's right! thank you. i suspected that was the problem, just didn't know if it's right to do like this because it's one parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Modify your command like this

```
INSERT INTO YourTable(val1, val2, val3 ...) 
VALUES(@val1, @val2, @val3...)
SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()
```

But i personally prefer to write a **stored procedure** and return the primary key as an output parameter of that sp.